# Configuring Policy-based Authorization in Blazor

Tags: authentication, asp.net-identity, blazor, identityserver4, policy

I am trying to implement Policy-based authorization in blazor server side. So I created a folder named `Policy` inside of Blazor project. Within that folder contains a file named `Policies.cs`. After implementing the contents of that file, I went to my `Startup.cs` file and added `services.AddAuthorization()` for the shared policies. After doing so, inside of my `Index.razor` file I made it where certain conditions need to be met in order to have specific views based on the user that has a specific role. If I login as a regular user, `BasicUser` then it will display what it should. **However**, when I login as an admin `SuperAdmin` it will display both IsUserPolicy & IsAdmin policy view. I do not understand why it is displaying both instead of one.

`Index.razor`:

```
@page "/"
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider GetAuthenticationStateAsync


<AuthorizeView Policy="@Policy.Policies.IsUser">
    <p>You can only see this if you satisfy the IsUser policy.</p>
</AuthorizeView>

<AuthorizeView Policy="@Policy.Policies.IsAdmin">
    <p>You can only see this if you satisfy the IsAdmin policy.</p>
</AuthorizeView>
```

`Startup.cs` inside of `ConfigureServices method`

```
..... 

   services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(Policy.Policies.IsAdmin, Policy.Policies.IsAdminPolicy());
                options.AddPolicy(Policy.Policies.IsUser, Policy.Policies.IsUserPolicy());
            });
```

`Policies.cs`:

```
public class Policies
    {
        public const string IsAdmin = "IsAdmin";
        public const string IsUser = "IsUser";

        public static AuthorizationPolicy IsAdminPolicy()
        {
            return new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                                   .RequireRole("Admin")
                                                   .Build();
        }

        public static AuthorizationPolicy IsUserPolicy()
        {
            return new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                                   .RequireRole("Basic")
                                                   .Build();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something like this...

```
services.AddAuthorizationCore(options => options.ConfigurePolicies());
```

```
public static AuthorizationOptions ConfigurePolicies(this AuthorizationOptions options)
{
    options.AddPolicy(Policies.IsAdmin, policy => policy.RequireRole("SuperAdmin"));
}
```

[A repo with policies](https://github.com/BrianLParker/AuthApp)

Note the policies are defined in the shared library so they can be used in both the client and server

Comment: So basically I should separate IsAdmin and IsUser in its own separate class and place those policies under the shared folder?

Comment: Is ConfigurePolicies() something you created because I do not see that built in with AddAuthorizationCore?

Comment: @NoviceCoder yes its an extension method it should be placed inside a public static class...